# How to create a countdown bar animation in WPF(mvvm) with dynamic width and values bound to viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, mvvm

I want to create an animation of a bar (rectangle) going from its current width to 0 which will be used as visualization of a countdown.
In the end it should look somehow like this:
[image: Preview]
Right now my trigger to start the animation is set in a static class (this part already works).

```
        <Control x:Name="content" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0">
            <Control.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="FilledCountdownBar" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FFA4B5BF"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Managers:ActionModeManager.ShowUiTimer)}" Value="true">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="FilledCountdownBar"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" 
                            To="0" Duration="0:1:0" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Control.Template>
        </Control>
```

I got several points which I do not get to work here:

1. This view will be located in the bottom of a window, which is scaleable. So I do not know the starting width in pixels at the beginning of the animation. I would love to remove the "Width" from the *FilledCountdownBar* element to let it fill the whole space at the start automatically, but then I cannot animate that value (getting an exception).
2. When I do not set the "From" property of the animation, then the animation does not reset because there is no start value and the width will remain 0 after the animation finished playing the first time.
3. I have a property (Duration type) in my viewmodel which I want to bind to the duration of the animation. But it looks like I cannot do that in control templates? An exception is thrown:

> Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads.

I also tried to use a ProgressBar instead, but I could not get it animating smoothly. There were always small steps visible when changing the value, so like that it is not really an option for me.
Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to have dynamic animations that rely on Widths and things like this, I always do them in code as attached behaviors or in custom control code.

This allows you to create a `Storyboard` in code, set all its dynamic properties and then start it.

In this case, once the animation kicks off, it will be for the size of the control once it starts. If the user resizes the window while it's running, the animation won't dynamically scale itself. However, you can indeed make that happen. I just implemented your simple `DoubleAnimation`.

Here is a working example for your case:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Control x:Name="CountDownVisual"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Height="30"
            Margin="0">
            <Control.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <Grid x:Name="CountDownBarRootElement"
                            local:CountDownBarAnimationBehavior.IsActive="{Binding ShowUiTimer}"
                            local:CountDownBarAnimationBehavior.ParentElement="{Binding ElementName=RootElement}"
                            local:CountDownBarAnimationBehavior.TargetElement="{Binding ElementName=CountDownBar}">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="CountDownBar"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Fill="#FFA4B5BF" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Control.Template>
        </Control>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Attached Behavior

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    public static class CountDownBarAnimationBehavior
    {
        private static Storyboard sb;

        #region IsActive (DependencyProperty)
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsActive", typeof(bool), typeof(CountDownBarAnimationBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsActiveChanged));

        public static bool GetIsActive(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsActive(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnIsActiveChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(d is FrameworkElement control))
            {
                return;
            }

            if((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                if (GetParentElement(control) != null)
                {
                    StartAnimation(control);
                }
                else
                {
                    // If IsActive is set to true and the other properties haven't
                    // been updated yet, defer the animation until render time.
                    control.Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => { StartAnimation(control); }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StopAnimation();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ParentElement (DependencyProperty)
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentElementProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ParentElement", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(CountDownBarAnimationBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnParentElementChanged));

        public static FrameworkElement GetParentElement(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (FrameworkElement)obj.GetValue(ParentElementProperty);
        }

        public static void SetParentElement(DependencyObject obj, FrameworkElement value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ParentElementProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnParentElementChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!(d is FrameworkElement fe))
            {
                return;
            }

            // You can wire up events here if you want to react to size changes, etc.
        }

        private static void OnParentElementSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(sender is FrameworkElement fe))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (GetIsActive(fe))
            {
                StopAnimation();
                StartAnimation(fe);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region TargetElement (DependencyProperty)
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetElementProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TargetElement", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(CountDownBarAnimationBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static FrameworkElement GetTargetElement(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (FrameworkElement)obj.GetValue(TargetElementProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTargetElement(DependencyObject obj, FrameworkElement value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(TargetElementProperty, value);
        }
        #endregion

        private static void StartAnimation(DependencyObject d)
        {
            var parent = GetParentElement(d);
            var target = GetTargetElement(d);

            if (parent == null || target == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            sb = new Storyboard();
            var da = new DoubleAnimation();

            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, target);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("Width"));

            da.AutoReverse = false;
            da.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
            da.From = parent.ActualWidth;
            da.To = 0d;

            sb.Children.Add(da);

            sb.Begin();
        }

        private static void StopAnimation()
        {
            sb?.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is works very nicely and I think I do understand how it is works. About the " If the user resizes the window while it's running, the animation won't dynamically scale itself. "-part: I was aware of this behavior, and actually willing to accept this limitation.But if you can suggest a better approach I would gladly take a look at it. :-)